# Java Generics question mark in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have an API with a signature in Java that return `public Foo<?> getFoo()`

Then when I try to consume that API from Scala, is complaining about `?`.

```
val fooValue:Foo[_] = API.getFoo()
```

I also try with Any

```
val fooValue:Foo[Any] = API.getFoo()
```

Any idea how can I set the question mark type in Scala

Comment: Can the compiler infer a type?

Comment: The compiler cannot infer the wildcard type "?" the IDE is not complaining, but when I compile the error rise

Comment: What is the **exact** error message? And show a complete code example that causes it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code compiles

*Foo.java*

```
public class Foo<T> {
}
```

*API.java*

```
public class API {
    public static Foo<?> getFoo() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

*App.scala*

```
object App {
  val fooValue: Foo[_] = API.getFoo()
}
```

<strike>`Foo[?]` is not valid Java syntax.</strike>

If the method is `public static Foo<?> getFoo()` you can call it like `API.getFoo()`. If it's `public Foo<?> getFoo()` you can call it like `new API().getFoo()`.

Question mark (`?`) in Java corresponds to underscore (`_`) in Scala.

Comment: You create the Foo class with generic T. In my case I cannot have it a generic type T

Comment: Write your definition of class `Foo`. What do you mean by "cannot have it a generic type T"?

Comment: Sorry, yes we have the Foo[T] in the definition of the class, but still is not working for me.

Comment: Write definitions of your classes and write compile errors.

Comment: I fixed making a instanceOf getFoo().asInstanceOf[Foo[Any]]